# best way to create this android view hierarchy?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, android-fragments, interface

Being new to Android development, I am wondering what is the best way to make such a UI.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Details:

- There can be an unspecified number of blocks.
- One or many new Blocks can be added by buttons or text activities in existing boxes.
- Each of the blocks can hold multiple views - text, images, buttons, or a combination, etc.
- A new block can enter either from the bottom of the screen or the side (This is just to illustrate that boxes have to be animated)
- The blocks can be dismissed by swiping them to the left or right. The remaining just stack below one another.
- The new blocks being added or removed should go through the 'state stack' - hitting the back button should restore the previous state.
- Hitting the back should go back to the previous state.

I decided to model each box as a fragment and have a bunch of classes inheriting from a common parent 'BoxFragment'. But what I've learnt so far from stackoverflow and other android tutorials that there is no way to add an unspecified number of fragments to a layout. For each fragment, the layout xml needs a place holder.

With this information, what will be the best way to construct this UI hierarchy?

Comment: where did you read that you cannor add multiple fragments to the same container?

Comment: You can, but only if they have a placeholder in the layout xml. The method call,

`fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "my_fragment");`

needs

`<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    class="com.fragments.BlockFragment">
</fragment>`

to be in the layout xml.

I instead want an unspecified number of Blocks to be added.

Comment: No, you can create multiple fragments by new MyFragment() and add them to the parent container